# Git: managing files on push event

Tags: git, github, githooks, git-push

I have a repository with a LaTeX project that includes the .pdf compiled and generated from the .tex file. I want the history and the source files to be private but the .pdf should be public and with a fixed URL. GitHub itself provides a fixed URL for the single file but in order to make it publicly available I need to set the repository public and this exposes also the history and all other files to the public.
Do you think there is a way where I can have GitHub (or BitBucket, or ...) to push the single .pdf file somewhere else so that it has a fixed unique and public URL? I thought I could somehow push it to AWS's S3 or have a Lambda receiving a HTTP call and going to fetch the single file but there could be a far easier way I don't know.

Comment: You probably are looking for git hooks - https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks.  Git hooks provide an interface to run code on push events, code commits, etc.

Comment: @MaxFriederichs yeah I was looking at the hooks but I cannot seem to be fully understanding how they work. Can I have a HTTP POST or PUT call fire with a file attached after a push? Do they all run local or I can have some run server-side, considering I'm not hosting my own repository?

Comment: Yes, what you are describing in this comment are not traditional "hooks" but rather a construct of GitHub called "WebHooks".  They can POST a payload with information about a given event.  You would write a small server that would listen for these payloads. More reading: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's how I worked it out (many thanks to @cmbuckley who pointed me in the right direction).

I created a very simple index.html file in the repository with the TeX project:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href = "EXISTING_FILE_NAME";
        link.download = "NEW_FILENAME";
        link.click();
    });
</script>
```

I then set up the repository to serve the `master` branch for the git-page. I then used my own domain and created a subdomain on CloudFlare, that owns the NameServers of my domain, pointing it to my GitHub page, and set the 
same subdomain on the repository as my custom domain address.

What happens now is this: a user goes to the custom subdomain, he gets the index.html page that automatically downloads the file in the most recent version as it's the one served. Yet the repository is private and even the name of the file gets changed so nobody sees it.

Comment: Didn't realise yours was also to build a CV :-)

Comment: @cmbuckley yeah! I saw yours had the same goal ;)  I don't know how you got that mine is for the CV as well though

Comment: I guessed your Stack Overflow username was the same as your GitHub one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Continuing off of Max's answer, one solution could be to maintain separate private and public repos. I like this option because you would not have to introduce another service. Your workflow might look something like this:

1. Compile your PDF locally in your private repo
2. Commit the changes to your private repo
3. Have a post-commit git hook to copy the compiled PDF to your local public repo
4. Push from your local public repo to Github

For the post-commit hook, create a file called `post-commit` (no extension) in the git `.git/hooks` directory. Then simply put a bash command inside that file that copies the PDF from the private repo to the public repo, e.g: `cp ~/private-repo/document.pdf ~/public-repo/document.pdf`.

Comment: This requires more than one interaction from me. I'd like to set something up so that with only one push everything works out. Otherwise I could just manually upload the file somewhere, if the whole thing gets me to do more than the single push it won't be so much of a gain ;)

Comment: Perhaps you could combine this method with moving the PDF into a Dropbox or Google Drive folder that automatically syncs then?

Answer (score 2):

You could use GitHub pages on a private repository to achieve this. From [the documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/):

> GitHub Pages sites are publicly available on the internet, even if their repositories are private.

You could commit code to the `master` branch and have a CI tool run the build steps, force remove the source files and commit the PDF all to the `gh-pages` branch. If this was to a user page (e.g. username.github.io repository), then the same applies, but GitHub pages is built from `master` branch, so you'd need to use something like a `release` branch for your build tool to listen to.

I use a [similar workflow](https://github.com/cmbuckley/cv) to build a PDF from a .tex file using Travis. The source is public, but the workflow would work for a private repository. The only problem with this is that Travis public version cannot work on private repositories, but [Travis Pro](https://travis-ci.com/) and other tools like [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) can do this.